# why is CSS stylesheet partly not working in my Django app? Is it something to do with retrieving database data?

Tags: html, css, django, postgresql

I believe I have all the Django settings correct as I have followed a few tutorials including a Linkedin one. I think I have identified where the problem occurs. The CSS stylesheet does work on my app everywhere except at the part of the code where I am retrieving postgres data.In addition when I modify the code and remove the postgres code the CSS will work and style that area. Therefore I don't understand why it stops working when I add the postgres! I have also included {% load static %} at the top of my HTML.

I include my HTML the code below..

Code Snippet when it works:

```
  <div class="skills">
    <h2>Stories!!!!</h2>
    <div class="skill-row">
      <img class="princess-img" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/ZETg64fW7xb0gr4NEz/giphy.gif" alt="princess-img">
      <h3><a href="Repunzel.html">Repunzel!!</a></h3>
      <p>Lets see hdewdow Repunzel manages to escape the tower, have an adbenture and finds out the truth!!.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="skill-row">
      <img class="alladin-img" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/OoOvAC7vASedB6EhpS/giphy.gif" alt="alladin-img">
      <h3><a href="Alladin.html">Alladin!!</a></h3>
      <p>Let's see if Kitty, Jasmine and Alladin manage with Genies' help to outsmart the baddies!!.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

/*When it doesn't work*/

```
 <div class="skills">
    <h2>Stories!!!!</h2>
    
    {% for drawing in drawings.all %}

    <div class="skill-row">
      <img class="{{drawing.classname}}" src="{{drawing.source}}" alt="{{drawing.classname}}">
      <h3><a href="{% url 'detail' drawing.id %}" >Repunzel!!</a></h3>
      <p>{{ drawing.summary }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

drawing is my drawing object that I included in my model definition and it is stored in postgres. I do connect to the database as i retrieve the data. The whole issue is that the CSS styling for that specific part doesn't work when included in the django for loop.

I also include the views and models code below...

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import Drawing

def drawingshome(request):
drawings = Drawing.objects
return render(request, 'drawings/drawingshome.html',{'drawings':drawings})

#models.py
from django.db import models

class Drawing(models.Model):
 image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
 summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 classname = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='0000000')
 source = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='0000000')
 altname = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='0000000')


def __str__(self):
    return self.summary
```

Many thanks for your help and your time.

Comment: Please show the view you use for this template. And the model Drawing.

Comment: I am assuming `source` field is `ImageField` then: `{{ drawing.source.url }}`

Comment: thank you for your replies. I have edited my question to include the models and views code.

Answer (score -1):

Declare a variable.

```
drawings = 'postgres_db_data'
```

Try:

```
{% for drawing in drawings %}
```

Note: I have removed .all and 'postgres_db_data' is your DB query instance.

I have done the same in many of development and succeeded.

Comment: How can this answer help?

Comment: If you wanted to use some placeholder something like `MyModel.objects.all()` would have been much better or even simply a comment `# Your data`. As of now your answer doesn't make much sense.